# What is the name of this story

Tags: story-identification

I saw this story somewhere and can't remember the name. Here's what I know..

- This gem fell from like a giants or goblins crown.
- They found it in the centre of the earth.
- There was a small "person" turning this lever and this whole contraption.
- The gem was in it and its what made the earth spin.
- They made some agreement but I think it failed so the earth stopped spinning and everything fell apart.

Any idea, some of it might be incorrect BTW.

Comment: Was this a short story or a novel? And in roughly which year did you read it?